# Sublime text 2: difference between Sublimerge vs FileDiffs plugins

Tags: sublimetext2, file-comparison

I want to do some file comparison in `Sublime Text 2`, I have done a bit of research and found out that:

1. Sublime text has a built-in diff feature but its features are limited `open a folder (Click "File" | "Open Folder..." And choose a folder at a level that contains both files), Sumblime Text 2 will open a new window. Multi-select the two files you want to compare in the sidebar, then right-click and choose "Diff Files...".` see [quora.com/Sublime-Text/Can-you-compare-files-code-within-Sublime-Text-2](http://www.quora.com/Sublime-Text/Can-you-compare-files-code-within-Sublime-Text-2)
2. There are 2 good plugins that do the job: [`Sublimerge`](http://www.sublimerge.com/) and [`FileDiffs`](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeFileDiffs)

However I could not find a clear explanation of the differences between them. I suspect that rather that one beeing better than an other, one would fit one type of usage more than another, but I may be wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just a small correction: you don't **need** to choose a folder at a level that contains both files - you can add multiple folders and multi-select between them.

Answer (score 3):

Sublimerge has the ability to ignore whitespaces and caps and generally is a more feature rich diff tool where as FileDiffs is good for quick and dirty diffs.

[Here](http://www.sublimerge.com/docs/configuration.html#default-settings-diff-algorithm) are some of the available options you can turn on and off in Sublimerge.

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding the difference of features (via editing your answer) ? Link to resources proving your points also welcome ;-)